# Data passed to view, not accessible in layout - Laravel Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

If I have this in my controller

`$this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index', $array);`

I can only access the data in `$array` inside the home.index.blade.php template file, and NOT in the `layouts.main` that I am using.

The layout & the view load correctly, I just cannot access any data passed in a controller from the layout file.

Anyone out there that can help?

To Clarify - Say I wanted to pass a `title` variable to my layout.main, how would I go about it? the method I posted above only allows me to access `$array` from within the 'content' of index.blade.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass data to the layout you use the first parameter as the name of the variable.

What is happening when you are doing this:

```
$this->layout->nest('content', 'home.index', $array);
```

Is nesting the view home.index that takes a parameter of $array. You are not creating a variable that can be used in the layout.

The variable you are creating for the layout is $content that will display the contents of the view passed to it, this is specific to the 'nest' method.

If you look into the API you will notice that 'layout' as declared in the controller is an instance of: `Laravel\View`

This has a method called `with` that supplies variables to the view.

To use it try something like this:

```
$this->layout->with( 'myVariable' , $variable_to_pass_to_layout )
             ->nest('content', 'home.index', $array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to make the data available across all your views with

`View::share('myVariable', $variable_to_pass_to_layout);`

Might be useful to let anyone access it.