# Laravel template - passing data to layout

Tags: php, laravel

How to pass data to layout file? I can only access the passed data on the content page but not on the layout file.

```
public function get_index($name){
    return View::make('widget.'.$name)
            ->with("title", ucwords($name).' &lsaquo; Document Management System');
}
```

Comment: It would help if you include your view files, both the content page and the layout file

Comment: I think this post maybe useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587357/data-passed-to-view-not-accessible-in-layout-laravel-controllers

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
View::share('data', $data);
```

on your `before` filter or in `__construct` of your `Base_Controller`.

Answer (score 3):

You need a global view variable. I think you need to look at `View::share('title', $title);` 
I also think you can chain it with `->shares('title', $title)`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$this->layout->with('foo', 'bar')` from within an action to make a variable `foo` available to your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation recently where I needed to dynamically change the @include('layouts._sidebarLeft') statement in my master template. View::share($key, $value) solves this. I then changed my template to @include($key)  and whenever I need to change it from the default one, I just run another View::share() before returning the view in my controller. I defined the default sidebar within /start/global.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `View::share()` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

The docs for 7.x says to call this method in the ServiceProvider.